# Can I use a Vivitar Auto Thyristor 3700 Flash with my Nikon D3100?

Tags: nikon-d3100, hotshoe-flash, vivitar

Can I Use my very old  Vivitar Auto Thyristor 3700 Flash with my DSLR Nikon D3100?

Answer (score 1):

Nikon is supposed to be 250 volts for their circuit and the Vivitar 3700 has been measured around 9 volts from a few different sources, so in theory the answer is yes. Having said that, there's really very little reason to use such an old flash, you're much better off getting a modern flash from Nikon that you can control properly from the camera body rather than risking a faulty circuit in an old flash and damaging your camera.